# Instances calling method seem to reference same list

Tags: python, methods, pygame, self, instances

I am working through Cravens pygame tutorial and need some clarification.
Here is the code that is causing the issue:
CODE1:

```
import pygame
import random

# Define some colors
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("'Classy' Snow Globe")

class Snowstorm():
    snow_list = []
    snow_num = 0
    snow_size = 0
    snow_speed = 0


    def get_snow(self):

            for i in range(self.snow_num):
                    x = random.randrange(0, 700)
                    y = random.randrange(0, 500)
                    self.snow_list.append([x,y])

    def draw_snow(self,screen):
            for i in range(len(self.snow_list)):
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,self.snow_list[i],2)
                    self.snow_list[i][1] = self.snow_list[i][1] + self.snow_speed

                    if self.snow_list[i][1] > 500: 
                            y = random.randrange(-50,-10)
                            self.snow_list[i][1] = y
                            x = random.randrange(0,700)
                            self.snow_list[i][0] = x

slow_storm = Snowstorm()
slow_storm.snow_num = 1
slow_storm.snow_size = 20
slow_storm.snow_speed = 1
slow_storm.get_snow()

med_storm = Snowstorm()
med_storm.snow_num = 2
med_storm.snow_size = 20
med_storm.snow_speed = 3
med_storm.get_snow()

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

screen.fill(BLACK)


slow_storm.draw_snow(screen)
med_storm.draw_snow(screen)


pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

The get_snow method seems to be creating the same list for both instances of my Snowstorm class.
Example:
 slow_storm calls get_snow method, the list is appended with [123,454]
 med_storm calls get_snow method, and gets the same list as slow_storm [123,454]

I changed the code by adding self.snow_list = [], and was able to produce the desired output.
CODE2:

```
 def get_snow(self):
            self.snow_list = []
            for i in range(self.snow_num):
                    x = random.randrange(0, 700)
                    y = random.randrange(0, 500)
                    self.snow_list.append([x,y])
```

I was also able to produce the correct output by using another variation of code.
CODE3:

I added this before the def get_snow(self):

```
 def __init__(self,list):
            self.snow_list=list
```

Then modified the instances to:

```
slow_storm = Snowstorm([])
med_storm.get_snow([])
```

Question:
1.  Why do the instances in the original code (CODE1) seem to be referencing the same list even though they are using self.snow_list?
2.  What are the differences that enable CODE2 and CODE3 to work properly?

Thank you.

Comment: `snow_list` is a class variable, not an instance variable: it is defined in the class scope, not in `__init__`. It is therefore shared by all instances of the class. If you want `snow_list` to be instance specific, define `self.snow_list = []` in `Snowstorm.__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the `snow_list = []` variable in the beginning of the class.  This makes it a class variable which keeps it the same across all instances of the class.  To make the lists separate, move `snow_list = []` to be under `def __init__():` part of the class.